# Regex to get specific word that is followed by text after it (in the SAME LINE) - JAVA

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm searching a Regular expression, that matches a specific word followed by any other words in the same line in multiline text, For example :

I have a small code to test on it:

in this code I want to matches all words that start with "@" and there is a words after it in the same line (the result that I want from this code, is to get the second @Override because there are some words and letters after it in the same line).

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

picture of example show what i want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the word `@Override` with a non-space character after it? Note that this would perhaps incorrectly grab comments if you have them on that line, but anyway this is a starting place.

- [`@Override(?=.*\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/GJ8cgS/1)

[image]